# What is the effective interest rate on a credit card that offers 0% interest with a 4% balance transfer fee?

Tags: credit-card, calculation, interest, transfer, balance

I'm about to do a balance transfer that has a fee of 4%.  It gives me 0% interest for 14 months.  Is it just a straight calculation of 4% for the year or is there another calculation that I need to include?

Comment: I am putting this comment here instead of as a comment on one of the answers.  Be very careful **not** to miss the deadline for paying off the balance transfer amount, not even by "just one day". Interest at the full cash advance interest rate will most likely be charged for the _entire 14-month period_ if you miss the deadline for repayment and you will lose all that you have saved and more.

Comment: I'll check on that, but I'm not sure it's set up in the same way as a short term "0% interest" promo for a store.  I'm paying a 4% fee up front so I'm guessing there's no chance they'll add it back in at the end of the term.

Comment: If you miss the deadline for repayment, you _will_ be charged interest at the cash advance rate for the entire 14 months, possibly reduced by the amount you prepaid, possibly not, and you _will_ be charged interest until that balance transfer amount is finally paid off. Worse yet, any purchases that you might make in the interim will also be charged interest from the time they post. **Don't** miss that deadline under any circumstances; pay off on-line three days ahead of schedule to avoid problems like "payments received over the weekend post on Monday" and "check was not received on time".

Comment: I just got off the phone with Discover and they confirmed that they do not do that.  There is no retroactive adding of interest when the promotional rate expires.  TO make it clear she said that even if I have a $100 balance left at the end the only thing that will happen is the $100 balance will be carried forward at the new interest rate.

Answer (score 4):

How much interest you effectively pay depends on when you pay off the balance transfer amount. If you pay off in a lump sum after the full 14 months, you have **pre-paid** 4% simple interest over a 14-month period. In effect, if you transferred a balance
of $100, paying $4 as the transfer fee, you have borrowed only $96 of the $100
that was used to pay off the *other* credit card company. Paying $100 at the end 
of the 14 month period is an interest rate of 100/96 - 1 = 4.1666% for 14 months
which works out to be an annual interest rate (APR) of 3.57%.  If you pay off in 
bits and pieces over 14 months, you will have paid interest at a larger rate.

Assuming you pay your credit card bill in full each month, does paying 
off each month's new charges count as having paid your credit card bill 
in full for that month so that new charges in the month following do not
get hit with interest from the time they are posted? If not, you will
end up paying a lot in these interest charges too. In short, **read**
the fine print of the balance transfer offer **very very carefully.**

Comment: According to the CARD act, payments are always applied to the oldest balance.

Comment: @littleadv Does that mean that once the balance transfer has occurred and the OP has paid off in full the balance shown as due on the _next_ credit card statement, all future payments will go towards reducing the balance transfer amount since that will be the oldest balance?

Comment: The card I'll be transferring to has a $0 balance.  It's true that all payments go towards the balance transfer first so they can get some interest on new purchases, but I won't be making purchases so all payments will go towards the balance transfer.

Comment: @Dilip:  "If you pay off in bits and pieces over 14 months, you will have paid a heck of a lot more."

I don't follow this statement?

Comment: @Moi relatively more. The amount you pay is fixed, but as a percentage of the debt it will be higher the faster you pay the debt off.

Comment: Xfer $1000 with a 4% fee ($40), then pay it off the next day. The result was that the rate was 4% per day.

Comment: Ah, I see.  The balance goes down but the fee never changes.  If I end up paying off the balance (will be difficult) I probably won't mind paying an extra $100 in interest since I'll be happy I paid it off.  If I can't pay it off I'll be happy knowing I'm at 3.43%.

Answer (score 2):

If you keep the whole balance for the whole 14 months and pay it off right before the interest raises, you'll end up with ~3.43% APR.

If you're going to pay off the balance gradually, then the effective APR will be higher.

Comment: So you're taking 4%, dividing by 14 months, then multiplying it by 12 months to get a yearly rate.

Comment: @Moi, yes, assuming you don't make any payments (balloon). Otherwise its much more complicated.

Comment: @Moi While littleadv did get 3.43% by dividing 4% by 12 and multiplying by 12 to get an APR, I don't think that that 4% is the right number to be using. If you transfer $100 paying a 4% transfer fee and then pay off $100 at the end of 14 months, you are _in effect_ borrowing $96 and paying off $100 at the end of 14 months, and so the interest charged is _effectively_ $4/$96 = 4.16666..% for 14 months, not 4%, and so the APR is actually about 3.57%, not 3.43%.

Comment: @Dilip I think that when you transfer $100 - you transfer $100, not $96. You get $104 as your balance.

Comment: Since I'm currently at 13.99% I come out ahead anyway you slice it since I won't be paying the card off during the 3.43% interest phase.  Even if I do it means my situation changed the the fee becomes a sunk cost in my mind, or almost like a type of insurance.  I suppose the real interest rate depends on the situation at that particular point in time.

Comment: @littleadv So once again it boils down to what the fine print says. In order of increasing probability, (i) If $100 balance transfer requires repayment of $104 after 14 months, that sure looks like interest even if they call it a transfer fee. (ii) If the $4 transfer fee is billed as a separate transaction from the balance transfer, $4 must be paid by the due date of the next billing statement to avoid interest charges on that. (iii) If the $4 fee is billed as a cash advance, interest is charged at the cash advance interest rate from the day it is posted till the day it is paid.

Comment: @Dilip I feel so happy now after reading your comment that I don't carry balances and never had the pleasure of reading all that fine print!

Comment: RE: 3.57 - I thought 100/96 as well. It depends how the fee hits, no? Also, if you need to leave room for fee to be added, you borrow $96, and see a balance of $99.84, not $100. So I went back to 3.43, and saw the discussions here were pretty complete.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer In a comment on the main question, the OP says that he is paying the fee upfront. Also the Discover Card site says in its FAQ (not hiding it in the fine print of the Cardmember agreement) that unless the _entire balance transfer amount_ **and** any other purchases are paid off in timely fashion when they appear on the _next_ monthly statement, _purchases_ will be charged interest even though the balance transfer is "interest-free" until the end of the agreed-upon period (14 months in this case).

Comment: Got it now, 3.57 it is.